# How to avoid the bottleneck to GPU in case of CNN ( Conv Neural Net )?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am using Keras ( with tensorflow ) to implement CNN, doing image classification. 
My GPU usage isn't crossing %1 , reasons I have found that it is due to delay in loading data into memory hence low GPU utilisation. 
But I am not getting how to implement it using keras.

Can anyone help me with code snippet that will avoid this bottleneck ?

( Suggestions I read are  to preload the data and parallelism etc. but I dont have any idea about it )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot to do here.

Firstly, you'll need a generator. It will give the data batch per batch. You can either write your own generator or leave keras to do it, use [this tutorial](https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly) in the first case. So basically a generator look like that :

```py
class DataGenerator(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):

    def __init__(self, ...):
        self.images = ...
        self.targets = ...
        self.batch_size = ...

    def __len__(self):
        return int(np.floor(len(self.images) / self.batch_size))

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.images[index*self.batch_size:(index+1)*self.batch_size], self.targets[index*self.batch_size:(index+1)*self.batch_size]
```

You can also use [keras preprocessing](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image) that will do that for you.

**This is very important if you want to use 100% of your GPUs.**

When your data generator is working, time to go for the parallelisation.

Parallelisation is made using a [distributed strategy](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/distributed_training)

```py
strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
with strategy.scope():
    model = # your keras model
    train_generator = DataGenerator(...)
    validation_generator = DataGenerator(...)
    test_generator =  DataGenerator(...)
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers...
    model.compile(loss=loss,
                  optimizer=optimizer,
                  metrics=['...'])
    model.fit(train_generator, validation_data=validation_generator, validation_freq=1,  epochs=FLAGS.epochs, callbacks=callbacks)
```

You'll have to put everything(data generator + model) under the scope of your distributed strategy. And that's it.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I ll implement this , it gave me the idea about what steps to follow.

Comment: If you have any question, do not hesitate :)

Comment: yeah sure , I ll try my best and even then if I couldn't , I ll post it tomorrow :)

Comment: 3 more things to look into would be if your CPU is bottlenecking your GPU. Look at  CPU usage while training. If it's say 90% then that may be it. The second would be how complicated your model is. A simple model on MNIST only used 5-10% of my GPU; a 12 layer CNN on cifar10 uses 90%. Third thing is batch size; if your batch size is really small then that could also bottleneck your GPU in my experience. Didn't think this would qualify as a full answer hence the comment. I have a Ryzen 3600x cpu and a gtx 970 gpu.

Comment: @chuckstables Thank you for the suggestion , I have reduced batch size from 32 to 2 then gpu usage spikes up from 1% to 6%. I have further reduced batch size to 1 i.e single image at a time then its  rise up to 7% .. its taking much less time than previous now.